# Add to array after button is pressed

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently playing around with array's, this is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>13.15</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form method="post">
         fruit: <input type="text" name="fruit"><br><br>
         <input type="submit" name="add" value="add"><br><br>
         -------------------------<br><br>
         <input type="submit" name="sort" value="sort"> <input type="submit" name="shuffle" value="'shuffle'"><br><br>
         -------------------------
         <br><br>
      </form>
<?php
$fruit = array("Apple", "Mango", "Pear", "Banana");

if(isset($_POST['sort']))
{
sort($fruit);
foreach ($fruit as $key => $val) {
    echo "- " .  $val . "<br />" . "\n";
}
}

if(isset($_POST['shuffle']))
{
shuffle($fruit);
foreach ($fruit as $key => $val) {
    echo "- " .  $val . "<br />" . "\n";
}
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

What would be the best way to add fruit to the array? I have already created the buttons and input field for it but I can not seem to find the best code for it

Comment: If you want to add element in array use array_push() method!

Comment: Use JavaScript and AJAX for this purpose!

Comment: I prefer to use PHP only, I think I would have to work with sessions to make this work?

Comment: Yes, you need sessions

Comment: If you want it to persist you can use sessions (easiest), a cookie, local storage, or store it somehow in html (worst solution!)

Comment: Could you provide me with a small example for my code? I found a lot online but the examples are too complex

Comment: There is enough (simple) documentation out there: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp, http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm, ... You should research a bit and have a go at it. Only when you bump into a problem while doing, come back with a question about that problem.